# ora-65090: operation only allowed in a container database

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am not able to run any query to change to CDB or PDB in SQL plus it shows the above error.
For instance I tried running the query

```
Alter pluggable database open
```

and got this error.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65090: operation only allowed in a container database
```

Comment: This is a very special command. Can't you really run any query? Not even, say, `select sysdate from dual;`?

Comment: `alter session set container = cdb$root;`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sorry I meant no query to change to any PDB or CDB. I updated the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not it didn't work. Got this -------------------------------------- alter session set container = cdb$root
                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65090: operation only allowed in a container database

Answer (score 2):

The correct command to change Container is

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = containername;
```

If you are getting error then you must not be a privileged user
follow up this link for more information

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_pdb_admin.htm#GUID-E73BCAED-FF57-474A-A8C5-207D3F465413

Comment: Have you tried using service name of the container while login. Ex hr/hr@pdb2. Here use you CDB/PDB as connect identifier

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Though the solution is not a preferable one but it worked for me as of now. I used Database configuration assistant and deleted the pdb in which I getting connected to when logging using sqlplus. I would appreciate some proper solution to this.